# Obtain a table of proper size from a csv in Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, cell-array

I'm trying to obtain a table from a csv file in Matlab. The file is available at the following link: http://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/carData/SLID.csv

```
fid = fopen('SLID.csv', 'r');
C = textscan(fid, '%s %f %f %d %s %s', 'Delimiter', ',', ...
    'headerLines', 1, 'TreatAsEmpty','NA');
fclose(fid);

T = cell2table(C,...
    'VariableNames',{'id' 'wages' 'education' 'age' 'sex' 'language'});
whos T
```

But in such a way I obtain a 1x6 table, where each element is a cell of size 7425x1. How to obtain instead a 7425x6 table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the table you want using the *table* command:

```
T = table(C{1},C{2},C{3},C{4},C{5},C{6})
```

After that, you can set the column names using the table properties:

```
T.Properties.VariableNames{'Var2'} = 'wages';
```

etc.

Also, you may want to import the data using the %q specifier, which will remove the double quotes when reading the values from the file:

```
C = textscan(fid, '%q%f%f%d%q%q', 'Delimiter', ',',...
'headerLines', 1, 'TreatAsEmpty','NA')
```

But that depends on how you will work with the data later.